# limit_req in NGINX in Docker using webdevops/php-nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I don't suppose anyone would be prepared to outline for me how I might go about setting values for limit_req in NGINX in a Docker container using webdevops/php-nginx. I'm getting very occasional rate limit issues with a React/Laravel application and would like to try adjusting some rate limit settings.

The [customization section of the webdevops/php-nginx docs](https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-nginx.html#customization) suggests that to set "global configuration options the directory /opt/docker/etc/nginx/conf.d can be used. For vhost configuration options the directory /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.conf can be used". However, I'm not sure how I bring that into my Docker process:

```
docker build --file Dockerfile.prod -t ghcr.io/theotherdy/laravel-xmap-php-nginx:latest .
```

using Dockerfile.prod:

```
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:8.1-alpine
# These ENV variables refer to options in webdevops/php-nginx - https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-nginx.html
ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/public
ENV PHP_DISMOD=bz2,calendar,exiif,ffi,intl,gettext,ldap,imap,pdo_pgsql,pgsql,soap,sockets,sysvmsg,sysvsm,sysvshm,shmop,xsl,zip,gd,apcu,vips,yaml,imagick,mongodb,amqp
# sets working directory for any future actions
WORKDIR /app
# ie copying from wherever docker is run to WORKDIR
COPY . .  
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
COPY .env.prod .env
# recommended optimization from: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment
RUN composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN php artisan key:generate
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan view:cache
# Ensure all of our files are owned by the same user and group.
RUN chown -R application:application .
```

and docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: "3" services:
    app:
        image: ghcr.io/theotherdy/laravel-xmap-php-nginx:latest
        ports:
            - '9000:80'
        volumes:
            - ./storage:/app/storage
        #env_file: '.env'
        depends_on:
            - db
        restart: always
    db:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        container_name: xmap-db
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xx'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'xx'
            MYSQL_USER: 'xx'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'xx'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 0
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always 
    volumes:
        db-data:
```

Any advice/pointers very gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the container, if you navigate to `/opt/docker/etc/nginx` you'll find this structure :

[image]

Any `.conf` file added inside `vhost.common.d` will get loaded inside the `server` context, so you could `COPY` your own file there in `Dockerfile` to add the settings you want :

```
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:8.1-alpine
# ...
COPY my-nginx-settings.conf /opt/docker/etc/nginx/vhost.common.d/custom.conf
# ...
```

If you need to add global settings, add the file in `conf.d`.